# Google social login routing isssue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I tried much time to route to the dashboard using social login with google, but when google login API hit and gives me 200 ok response, then dashboard showing at the bottom of the sign-in page, means sign in form and dashboard are shown on the same page. How can I resolve this issue?

```
function () {
  if((data.meta.code === 200)){
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.router.navigate(['/document',], );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not working still signin and dashboard shown on same page. Thank you so much for your support but do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right

```
this.router.navigate(['/document',], );
```

I suppose it should be something like

```
this.router.navigate(['/document', {}]);
```